# Why does TypeScript implicitly convert Uint8Array to Float32Array

Tags: typescript

Why does TypeScript not throw an error when a `Uint8Array` is passed into a function expecting an `ArrayBuffer`? I assume it must be implicitly convertible, but if you use it later it results in incorrect behaviour. For example in my case I was converting it to a Float32Uint but it cast each element instead of mapping it. Is there any way to get TypeScript to catch this sort of error.

```
function test(data: ArrayBuffer)
{
  console.log("Bytelength " + data.byteLength);
  let view = new Float32Array(data);
  console.log("Size of Float32Array " + view.length);
}

var uint_array : Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(4);

console.log("Test passing wrong type");
test(uint_array);
console.log("Test passing correct type");
test(uint_array.buffer);
```

Output is:

```
Test passing wrong type
Bytelength 4
Size of Float32Array 4
Test passing correct type
Bytelength 4
Size of Float32Array 1
```

Edited to add a simpler example to show the issue. I pass in a type that is clearly wrong. The log outputs the wrong type, but TypeScript is fine with it.

```
function test(data: ArrayBuffer)
{
    console.log("Type of data " + data.constructor.name);
}

var uint_array : Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(4);

test(uint_array); 
test(uint_array.buffer);

> Type of data Uint8Array
> Type of data ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: The test function expects an ArrayBuffer, but in the first case I am passing in a Uint8Array without it complaining. I guess I expected that could be caught. And in reality when I call it the first time: test(uint_array), the object in the function is actually a Uint8Array not an ArrayBuffer like typescript indicates.

Comment: Oh I see, a `Uint8Array` is not technically an `ArrayBuffer` but can apparently be used as one in some circumstances?  Let me look into it more

Comment: sorry about my confusion earlier; I had initially misunderstood your issue.  It's an interesting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), so you can assign a `Uint8Array` to something that expects an `ArrayBuffer` if the structure of `ArrayBuffer` is satisfied by `Uint8Array`.  It has nothing to do with the type *names* or *declaration sites*.

The definitions for `Uint8Array` and `ArrayBuffer` are split among a lot of different declaration files, but the main one is [`lib.es5.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/534fc14c662cc49c1c71f3830b32f98ff7472e87/lib/lib.es5.d.ts).

[The definition of `ArrayBuffer`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/534fc14c662cc49c1c71f3830b32f98ff7472e87/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1574-L1584) is

```
interface ArrayBuffer {
    readonly byteLength: number;
    slice(begin: number, end?: number): ArrayBuffer;
}
```

and [the definition of `Uint8Array`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/534fc14c662cc49c1c71f3830b32f98ff7472e87/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L2038-L2280) contains

```
interface Uint8Array {
    // ...
    readonly buffer: ArrayBufferLike;
    // ...
    readonly byteLength: number;
    // ...      
    slice(start?: number, end?: number): Uint8Array;
    // ...
}
```

And so the compiler sees `Uint8Array` as assignable to `ArrayBuffer`.  That's just how it is.

---

This was reported as [microsoft/TypeScript#31331](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31311) which was closed as a duplicate of [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202)
which is the catch-all issue for providing a way to support nominal typing.  You only want something to be a valid `ArrayBuffer` if it is *declared* to be, not if it happens to match the structure.

---

There are workarounds which simulate nominal typing.  One approach is to  [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) a member into the `ArrayBuffer` interface to make `TypedArray`s incompatible with it.  [This is called "branding"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible).  Such a brand property doesn't really exist at runtime, it's just a way for TypeScript to tell the difference between `ArrayBuffer` and otherwise-compatible things:

```
// merge a brand property
interface ArrayBuffer {
  __ArrayBufferBrand: true;
}
```

And that prevents the bad call:

```
console.log("Test passing wrong type");
test(uint_array); // error! 
// Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer'.
```

Hooray!  But it also prevents the *good* call:

```
console.log("Test passing correct type");
test(uint_array.buffer); // error!
// Argument of type 'ArrayBufferLike' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer'.
```

Boo! The problem is that the `buffer` property of `uint_array` is typed as `ArrayBufferLike` which is not exactly `ArrayBuffer`. `ArrayBufferLike` [is defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/534fc14c662cc49c1c71f3830b32f98ff7472e87/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1589-L1592) like

```
type ArrayBufferLike = ArrayBufferTypes[keyof ArrayBufferTypes];

interface ArrayBufferTypes {
    ArrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer;
}
```

which also gets [merged into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) from [`SharedArrayBuffer` in another declaration file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/src/lib/es2017.sharedmemory.d.ts#L4-L16).

So we need to make sure that `ArrayBufferLike` is assignable to `ArrayBuffer`, meaning we need to also merge that brand property into `SharedArrayBuffer`:

```
interface SharedArrayBuffer {
  __ArrayBufferBrand: true;
}
```

And now everything works the way we want:

```
console.log("Test passing wrong type");
test(uint_array); // error! 
// Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer'.
console.log("Test passing correct type");
test(uint_array.buffer); // okay
```

Hooray again!

---

But that's a lot of effort to prevent this problem, and if `ArrayBufferLike` ever gets more members in it, you might have to manually merge into those members.  And maintaining this yourself might be more trouble than it's worth.  I guess it's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngIQK4wzTIDeAsAFDLID6N6muBRUOmIAJgFzJhR4QA3JQC+lSqEixEKAMoALOFAgcG2fIWLkqtehnXNobOJx58BwimIriKMPCARhgAexC8IAZzAAKDnDA4HjUmTSgASlJKagQ3TxcAGwgAOgSXAHMfACIcLEgkkHSweWQs5ABqZH9A5IAjPIgAGQhC4vDLaiSwZAA3YAgAd2QAXmQQQeQAMTSAgGYAJhC-ALh26ORYkHik1Izs2WAALxQXGCmZsAWQ0ore-oHUlqL5NatbHqVkPEkaJUYeACqkgAHNdRuMhkDwKD9FgfAAWV6UTbbFJpTJZAAqXm6AAc4J5PKB0sgBlA3CSwFhcRAsq9IN4fN9wL9Ye1kAB6DnIaDkqAAQmQlC5aCg6TwAFsWt1TrxqSgAORQsAwxgK5DATxjFzdAlE9IgOC1JK8FzIfGYKVSZCyqk05AKkIaFgK5LIuKJNF7LE48164kbFwYCBOOU0umWBm+ZlgVmMOqGCKCTnclwAa2wthFvKDgpF6HFUvANrOdsVTsTjWAaYg6s12t1hOABqNJrAZotcCtxFt8odFbCrtstiAA)